# How can I generate specific Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to generate some URL like http://mysite/some-id  using below method?
Note: **I do not want to use controller name and action name in url**. because the main site used this structure and my boss does not want to change it.

```
public class StoryController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            if(id =="some-id"){

            }
           return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would use routing which is defined in the global asax

Comment: *I do not want to use controller name and action name in url*..... why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what version of MVC you are using, but if you are on the newest version or .NET Core, if you used routing attributes, you'd achieve this by:

```
[Route("")]
public class StoryController : Controller
{
    [Route("{id}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        if(id =="some-id"){

        }
       return View();
    }
}
```

Having a single parameter that is a string on your index-like route will definitely pose problems later with the routing engine though, when you try to add more controllers and views

Comment: I am using MVC 5 controller and visual studio 2015

Comment: error at : [HttpGet("{id}")]  , 'HttpGetAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Try changing `HttpGet` back to `Route` for MVC5